# Axios - Interceptors not working on request error - 401 code

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a simple react app that is using a third API to fetch data. Before making any requests, a token must be retrieved in order to use it in the headers. This token is created by using the same API by passing the client id and secret id - the API is Artsy API. This token has an expiration date so this API must be requested if the token doesn't not exist. After getting the token, then I can call other requests without a problem.

I have set up the API requests in a separate file, like so:
Apis.js

```
import Axios from 'axios';
const baseURL = 'https://api.artsy.net/api';

// set up xap-token and set tot default headers
const instance = Axios.create({
    baseURL: baseURL + '/tokens/xapp_token',
    params: {
        'client_id': process.env.CLIENTID,
        'client_secret': process.env.CLIENTSECRET
    }
});

instance.interceptors.request.use(undefined, err => {
    const status = err.response ? err.response.status : null;
    console.log("auth",err.response)

    if(status === 401){
        console.log("auth",err.response)
        return 'hello'
        // this.getAuthToken();
    }
});

export default{

    getArtworks: function(){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            instance.get(baseURL + '/artworks')
            .then(res => {
                resolve(res)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    },

    getArtists: function(){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            instance.get(baseURL + '/artists')
            .then(res => {
                resolve(res)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                reject(err);
            });
        });

    },

    getTest: function(){
        return 'hello';
    }
};
```

Not really sure how to use the `create` and `interceptors`, but I created an Axios instance. So the idea is to create some sort of middleware, create an instance and then use it as an interceptor if there is a request on that error.  If there is, then apply the token to that instance and proceed with the request, `retry`.  Also not sure how to set the the token in the instance.

So far I'm getting a 401 error in the `getArtists` method, this api gets called when the page loads, it's under `componentDidMount`.

App.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Apis from './utils/Api';
import Gallery from './components/Gallery';

class App extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            artWorks: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        // Apis.getArtists();
        Apis.getArtists().then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            // this.setState({
            //     artWorks: res.data
            // })
        });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Gallery artists={this.state.artWorks}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

This is the [api](https://developers.artsy.net/v2/docs/authentication) doc links for authentication.

Can anybody help? not really sure how to use the instance as a "middleware"? new to Axios.  I would like to avoid 3rd library middleware, I prefer to learn in a manual way than using 3rd libraries.  Your help will be much appreciated

**Update:**

I was able to get this somewhat working, i modified the `instance.interceptor`:

```
instance.interceptors.response.use(undefined, err => {
    const status = err.response ? err.response.status : null;
    if(status === 401){
        console.log("auth",err.response)

        instance.post(err.config.authURL, err.config.auth).then(res => {
            let token = res.data.token;
            err.config.headers['X-XAPP-Token'] = token;
            console.log('calling',err.response)
            return instance.request(err.config)
        });
    }

    // return Promise.reject(err);
});
```

But I'm getting undefined in the `getArtists` response. Not sure what's going on here.  Here is a screenshot of the console:

[image]

Comment: Have you check the environment variables from `process.env` are being pulled into your app?

Comment: It should also be noted that you shouldn't have secrets (`CLIENTSECRET`) in your frontend code unless it's a privately consumed app.

Comment: env variables are being pulled into the app, they are stored in an `.env` file.  Looks i'm getting error in the Axios.create, getting a 401 code but the url and the params are being passed correctly.  I have added the docs for the API authentication

Answer (score 9):

You should use `instance.interceptors.response` rather than `instance.interceptors.request` .

Because the request interceptor is called before Ajax request send.  I think the response interceptor is actually what you want here.

---

1. About BaseURL, you should set like below

```js
const instance = Axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://api.artsy.net/api'
})
// because you set the baseURL of the instance
// this will request url https://api.artsy.net/api/artworks
instance.get('/artworks')
```

2. About 401 Error you get, from the api doc you give.I think you should request to get the token before your app start.

```js
instance.post('tokens/xapp_token').then(res => {
  /* here is the response
{
  "type" : "xapp_token",
  "token" : "...",
  "expires_at" : "2014-09-05T12:39:09.200Z"
}
  */

  // you can set common request headers like this
  // or use request interceptors here to set headers
  // then every request you sent by instance after will have X-XAPP-Token header
  instance.defaults.headers.common['X-XAPP-Token'] = res.token
})
```

---

Actually `err.config.headers['X-XAPP-Token'] = token;` this code will not affect the request headers.

Comment: ah I see, yeah this should have been `response` instead of `request`.  Problem I'm running into is that I can't see the token.  So I was hoping when I created the instance, I would get the token from the auth request, but I don't see the token.  i would need the token so i can set it in the `error.config.header` and retry the request `getArtists`

Answer (score 2):

Even I was facing same issue, it is resolved by using below code

```
export const instance = axios.create({ baseURL: API_BASE_URL })
    const instance = axios.create();
    instance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
      console.log(`response ${response}`);
      return response;
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(`error ${error}`);
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });

instance.interceptors.request.use(
            (config) => {
                if (this.isUserLoggedIn()) {
                    localStorage.setItem(APP_TOKEN, token)
                    config.headers.Authorization = token
                }
                return config
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have initally faced same problem due interceptor not called until component get mounted. After that i have factured code now its working fine. see the code below how i did in correct way

***httpConfig.js***

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { baseURL } from '../utils/config'
import { SetupInterceptors } from './SetupInterceptors'


const http = axios.create({
    baseURL: baseURL
})

SetupInterceptors(http)

export default http
```

***SetupInterceptors.js***

```
import { baseURL } from '../utils/config'


export const SetupInterceptors = http => {

    http.interceptors.request.use(
        config => {
            config.headers['token'] = `${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
            config.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json'
            return config
        },
        error => {
            const status = error?.request?.status || 0
            const resBaseURL = error?.request?.config?.baseURL
            if (resBaseURL === baseURL && status === 401) {
               if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
                  localStorage.clear()
                  window.location.assign('/')
                  return Promise.reject(error)
               } else {
                  return Promise.reject(error)
               }
            }
            return Promise.reject(error)
        }
    )

    http.interceptors.response.use(function(response) {
        return response
    }, function (error) {
        const status = error?.response?.status || 0
        const resBaseURL = error?.response?.config?.baseURL
        if (resBaseURL === baseURL && status === 401) {
            if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
                localStorage.clear()
                window.location.assign('/')
                return Promise.reject(error)
            } else {
                return Promise.reject(error)
            }
        }
        return Promise.reject(error)
    })
}

export default SetupInterceptors
```